# FPDF insert text but with dynamic fields

Tags: php, jquery, forms, fpdf

I'm using this solution to give users the option to create more fields.
It's limited in 25 fields.
I create the option to print this form, I'm using FPDF.
But as the form can have until 15 fields I would like to know if there is a good way to do this.
I can't imagin a good way.
I don't want to print all (25 fields) with FPDF and have many blank fields.

Comment: You have a html form that may have 25 fields, right? And if only 15 of them have filled in data, you want to put only these 15 into the PDF, right?

Comment: exactly! but I'm looking for a good way to do this. I still don't know

Answer (score 1):

You linked PHP.  Can't you simply loop through 25 times, and if there is a value, you display it.  If not, you don't.  This would also help with someone entering values in the 1, 3, 5...  rows, leaving the others blank.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simplier if you will make the name form elements as an Array:

```
<input name="fields[]" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" />

foreach($_POST['fields'] as $key=>$value) 
{
   if(!empty($value))
   {
        //do FPDF stuff here...
   }
}
```